# JavaScript .push() inside function is overriding global variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I have the following problem with `.push()` method:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function add(arr) {
    arr.push("e");
    return arr;
}

add(myArray);

// myArray is now  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Why it overrides `myArray`? Can't understand that...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-is-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: I added an alternate solution. When you do `.slice()` you're having to make a copy of the array, store it, `.push()` the new value in, then return the copy. I've used `.concat()`, which will let you pass in the original array, and perform all the above steps at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays in Javascript (and most other languages) are passed by reference.

When you write `add(myArray)`, you are passing a reference to the same Array instance that the global `myArray` variable refers to.
Any changes to the array object will be visible through both references.

To copy the actual array instance, write `add(myArray.slice());`.
Note that this will not copy the objects inside of it.

Comment: Is there a simple way how to avoid that?

Comment: @Jany: you can't force an array to be passed by value - you'll have to copy it and then pass the copy as a reference, exactly as SLaks demonstrates.

Comment: You can pass a copy of the array by writing `add(myArray.slice());`

Comment: I think using slice method is very simple.

Comment: But if I write inside function `arr = "";`, `myArray` doesn't change. It hapens only with methods?

Comment: @Jany: By writing `arr = ""`, you are re-assigning the _variable_ to refer to a new instance.  That does not affect the original Array instance that `arr` used to refer to.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to be able to nest arrays, then I'd change the `.add()` function to have the `.concat()` duplicate the Array into a variable, `.push()` the new value into the new Array, and return it.

```
function add(arr) {
    var newArr = arr.concat(); // duplicate
    newArr.push("e");      // push new value
    return newArr;         // return new (modified) Array
}
```

---

You could use `concat()` as well, and return the new array it creates.

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function add(arr) {
    return arr.concat("e");
}
var newArray = add(myArray);

console.log( newArray );  // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
console.log( myArray );   // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

So instead of two methods `.slice()` then `.push()`, you accomplish it with one `.concat()`.

This also gives you the benefit of passing another Array instead of a string, so:

```
return arr.concat(["e","f"]);
```

would give you:

```
// ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

instead of:

```
// ["a", "b", "c", "d", ["e", "f"] ]
```

Comment: This is nice, thanks! But I need to put another array into... This doesn't work :( `arr.concat([["e","f"]]);`

Comment: @Jany - I updated my answer to `.push()` the value into the duplicate. You just pass the original Array into `.add()`, and it takes care of the duplication inside. This way, inside the `.add()` you have access to *both* Arrays, old and new.